# How to quote correctly with csquotes?

Tags: citing, punctuation, quoting, csquotes

I am unsure how to quote correctly using csquotes and `\textquote` and `\blockquote`. In the documentation I found this general advise: `\blockquote[cite][punct]{text}tpunct` but am unsure how to really use it to get consistent quotation. I am using `\autocite` with `biblatex`, so at the moment I write it like this:

```
\textquote{Knuth wrote in his famous book that LaTeX is superb} \autocite[86]{Knu86}.
```

I bet this is not the way to do it, and I am always mixing up the positions of `}`, `(Citation)` and punctuaction.

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 24):

I'm not quite sure what's ›correct‹ and ›incorrect‹ in your perspective, or what exactly you find problematic with the result you're currently getting. Maybe a minimal example would be helpful.

Here's what I do, and what has always (i.e., for about 5 years now) given me output that's correct by my standards. Over time, I've reduced the number of different ways of entering quotes to two:

For short quotes, or for things that are not quotes but just need quotation marks, single or double, I'm using `\MakeAutoQuote` in the preamble, so all I have to do is type in quotation marks directly, and let `csquotes` do the rest (the quotation marks  effectively trigger `\enquote` and `\enquote*` IIRC). I placed `»`, `«`, `›`, `‹` on [alt gr] + [2...5] on my keyboard, which helped a lot here. If I want it followed by a citation, I add plain old `\cite{...}` which is handled by `biblatex`.

For quotes that are longer, and that *might* have to be turned into a display quote in the output, I use `\blockcquote[123]{Knuth82}{blabla}`. It is, of course, `csquotes` that will decide if the quote has to be turned into a display one. That said, for texts whose layout I'm free to design myself, I've disabled display quotes completely: `\SetBlockThreshold{99},` plus a re-definition of the display quotes' style. They're marked by quotation marks like text quotes, plus their left margin is reduced by `\parindent.` (that latter aspect is not part of the example, though)...

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern,blindtext}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\MakeAutoQuote{»}{«}
\MakeAutoQuote*{›}{‹}
\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}

\begin{document}
»Knuth wrote in his »famous« book that LaTeX is superb«
\blindtext
\blockcquote[pre][post]{cite}{\blindtext etc}.
\end{document}
```

I don't let `cquotes` play with my punctutation, I feel more comfortable staying in control of it myself. Unless I have to follow someone else's style guide (or write in English), my order is always:

[quotation] - [closing mark] - [period or other punctuation] - [footnote mark]

[image]

Comment: This is already good advice. As I use Harvard style citations, I have some issues with this way of using csquotes. I will update my question...

Answer (score 10):

For the Harvard citation style I'm using something like this right now:

```
\blockquote[{\cite[109]{key}}]{Some interesting quote.}
```

For me it delivers the desired result:

Quote (Name + Year, p. 109)

It should also work for \textquote, but mind the extra `{}` inside the `[cite]` option from the standard form: `\blockquote[cite][punct]{text}tpunct`
Without them it didn't work for me.

Comment: For referenced quotes, `csquotes` has the `\blockcquote` command. Your example should result in the same output if you changed it to `\blockcquote[109]{key}{Some interesting quote}`. Note that you just have to provide the citation key without a `\cite` command and that it is a mandatory argument. Any optional arguments to `\cite` are carried over to the `\blockcquote` command.

Comment: @ThomasH It is actually not giving the same output. `\blockcquote[100]{key}{My quote.}` results in: “My quote.” Name Year, p. 100, whereas the use of `\blockquote` (without the c) puts brackets around author and year, as the initial question asked for.

Comment: I'm traveling at the moment, so i can't test it myself but I'd imagine that's just a case of setting up natbib or the csquotes cite command via `\SetCiteCommand`

Answer (score 3):

I need to answer instead of commenting because of not having enough reputation. But I think some people may find it useful to know that Thomas K is not getting the same output with `\blockcquote` and `\blockquote` because both commands have different hooks which print the final output.

For `\blockquote` it is `\mkcitation` which is defined with space and parenthesis: `\newcommand*{\mkcitation}[1]{ (#1)}`. For `\blockcquote` it is `\mkccitation` which is defined with space but without parenthesis: `\newcommand*{\mkccitation}[1]{ #1}`. So, if you redefine `\mkccitation` you can use `\blockcquote` and you get the same output and do not have to write `\cite` in combination with `\blockqote` every time.

Comment: For those who need something to cut and paste exactly, it's `\renewcommand*{\mkccitation}[1]{ (#1)}`. Make sure you add it after `\usepackage{csquotes}' so the default command is there to overwrite.