# Parentheses around cite with \blockcquote

Tags: citing, quoting, csquotes

I'm using `csquotes` and the `\blockcquote`-command

```
\blockcquote[p. 42]{life}{
    my quote
}
```

Which shows up as the quote indented, and citation as `Citation, p. 42`. This is fine, but I need parentheses around it, so it doesn't look weird with the quote ahead of the reference.

I could do (and am doing as of now)

```
\blockcquote{}{
    my quote \citep[p. 42]{life}
}
```

But in this case I could just as easily just used something to indent the text. There is no need for csquotes, when I'm not using anything else than indentation.

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103445/how-to-quote-correctly-with-csquotes), but the suggestions provided won't work for me. It lead me to believe that it has something to do with natbib, but I haven't found anything of relevance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `csquotes` package provides `\SetCiteCommand`, allowing you to set which cite command is used in all the `cquote` commands and environments (the default being `\cite`).

Putting `\SetCiteCommand{\citep}` in your preamble should give the desired result.

Source: `csquotes` package documentation, v5.2b, §8.6

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted because it directly answers my question, but I have not been able to test it as the need for the solution was no longer present at the time this answer came. Thanks anyway! =)

Comment: Works for me. Note though that `\SetCiteCommand` has to be called after your call to your citation package, so `\citep` is defined.